# How can a property be assigned during object construction with a value generated asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, constructor, prototype

**How can a property be assigned during object construction with a value generated asynchronously?**

I'm trying to assign a property to an object during construction that needs to be retrieved via AJAX:

```
//define module prototype
Library.Module = function () {
    this.resources = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {

        // assume that Library.require makes a request and 
        // then executes this callback
        Library.require(arguments[i], function (resource) {

            // ! the problem seems to be that 'this' is undefined 
            // in the scope of the callback
            this.resources[resource.location] = resource;
        });
    }
};
```

I think the intention of this code is rather clear - The problem is that `this` appears to be undefined in the scope of the callback function.

Comment: How about getting the value and then doing the construction within the complete function?

Comment: Not sure but storing current this in a variable above  (like var that = this) and then use that in your callback could not make the trick ?

Comment: @Pseudonym this happens to be for a little simplified version of a `require` implementation for my own use. If possible, I would enjoy being able to keep the functionality within the constructor so that I can simply use `var myModule = new Module('resourceName')`

Comment: @furrypet perhaps that will do the trick. I'm not sure.

Comment: Hmm I don't think you can get around using the completed (or equivalent) function the only other way I can think would be to make the async call within the constructor, set the value when it gets back, and then maybe have a call to function to do the rest of the work? I'm not sure kinda spitballing here

Comment: I saw that blog post recently, the last part could help you https://blog.engineyard.com/2015/mastering-this-in-javascript

Comment: Yes basically it's the advice I gave you to store it in another variable above

Comment: @furrypet I'm reading that now. Thanks; it's nicely written and helpful.

Comment: @Pseudonym you might be interested in the answer by furrypet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in the following article https://blog.engineyard.com/2015/mastering-this-in-javascript and following discussion in comments, a possible solution would be to store this in a variable higher in the scope to use it in the callback.

Therefore a possible solution could be :

```
Library.Module = function () {
    var _this = this;

    _this.resources = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {

      // assume that Library.require makes a request and 
      // then executes this callback
      Library.require(arguments[i], function (resource) {

        _this.resources[resource.location] = resource;
      });
   }
};
```

Useful snippet from the article cited:

> ## Managing this in a callback
>
> And that’s it: those are the four ways to set a function’s this value.
>   Those four rules are not too hard to remember, but there is a common
>   pitfall you should know about. I’m talking about callbacks. It’s easy
>   to be writing a callback and not even know it, like in setTimeout:
>
> ```
> setTimeout(function() {
>     $(‘button’).addClass(‘red’);
> }, 1000);
> ```
>
> The setTimeout function accepts a callback, but since it’s not using
>   one of the four rules for setting context, this defaults to the global
>   window object. That’s fine in the example above, but becomes a bug in
>   code like this:
>
> ```
> $('button').on('click', function() {
>     setTimeout(function() {
>         // Uh oh! `this` is the global object!
>         $(this).addClass('clicked');
>     }, 1000); 
> });
> ```
>
> We’re expecting $(this) to refer to the button that was clicked, but
>   it doesn’t, since this defaults to the global window object. One way
>   to solve this issue is to store our desired value of this in a local
>   variable and then simply use that variable in a child scope:
>
> ```
> $('button').on('click', function() {
>     var _this = this;
>     setTimeout(function() {
>         $(_this).addClass('clicked'); // All better
>     }, 1000); 
> });
> ```
>
> Of course there are many ways to accomplish the same thing. You could
>   use .bind(), .call(), or a number of other options. Choose what works
>   best for each individual situation.

Comment: I suggested an edit adding the snippet from the article, which I think was very helpful. You can accept that or disregard it. Thanks!

Comment: You were absolutely right, my mistake. Thanks a lot and happy coding ;)